# border to UIIMage

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to give border to `UIIMage` instead of `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

Once an `UIImage` has been created it cannot be modified. That includes adding a border.

Answer (score 0):

This effectively would mean drawing a border into the bitmap represented by the UIImage.  The easiest way to do this is to create a new bitmap altogether.  Create a new bitmap graphics context using CGBitmapContextCreate().  Draw your UIImage into it using CGContextDrawImage().  Draw your border using CGContextAddRect().   Finally, create a new bitmap using CGBitmapContextCreateImage().  You can get a UIImage from that using [UIImage imageWithCGImage: ]

Comment: ok fine.Thank you for giving answer. But after creating bitmap image can I fill color only on that image?

Comment: You can draw to the bitmap graphics context as long as you have it and haven't destroyed it.